# Please help me find a formula to find the 3rd point in a right triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm trying to figure out how to plot a 3rd point on a graph

Given the following line segments and angles

[image]

Is there a formula for the 3rd point?

Note: This image is just for an example.  The base line of the triangle will not always be parallel to the x-axis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the 90° vertex *A*, the 30° vertex *B* and the unknown vertex *C*

$$ \begin{pmatrix} x_C \\ y_C \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x_A \\ y_A \end{pmatrix} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}  \begin{pmatrix} -(y_B-y_A) \\ (x_B-x_A) \end{pmatrix}  $$

Example: *A* $=(1,1)$ *B* $=(5,2)$ *C* $= (1,1)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} (-1,4)$

[image: Alhpa]

Wolfram Alpha [Link](http://wolfr.am/16Of2xC)

Comment: Thank you very much, how did you calculate the 1/√3?

Comment: The factor is equal to $\tan \theta$. This comes from the cosine and inner product relationship [link](http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2006/07/dot-product-and-cosine.html)

Comment: @ja72 could you expand on that √3 and tan θ?

Comment: $$\tan(30°) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$  Also for a vector $(x,y)$ the perpendicular is $(-y,x)$ so point _C_ is on the line perpendicular to _AB_ and passing through _A_.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of finding it. The one I would favour in this particular scenario is:

1. Work out the length of the edge from the right angle to the point, using trig.
2. Find a unit vector from the right angle to the point.
3. Multiply and add.

The interesting one in the non-axis-aligned case is point 2, but it has a simple trick. You can easily find a unit vector from the right angle to the other point (vector subtraction), and then a 90 degree rotation takes $(x, y)$ to $(\pm y, \mp x)$ with the sign depending on the direction of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it is a right angled triangle, we know that the angle at the point $(?,?)$ is going to be $180 - (90 + 30) = 60$. Using the sine rule, we can then work out the length of that vertical line, which we get to be:

$$\frac{a}{\sin(A)} = \frac{b}{\sin(B)}$$
$$\frac{a}{\sin(30)} = \frac{10}{\sin(60)} \implies a = \frac{10}{\sin(60)} \cdot \sin(30) = \frac{10}{\sqrt3}.$$

This is your $y$ co-ordinate, and as you know that it is in a straight line up, you're $x$ co-ordinate will remain the same and so your point will be

$$\left( 10, \frac{10}{\sqrt3} \right).$$

Comment: Thank you for the help, but it won't always be a straight line up.  As the baseline won't always be parallel to the x-axiss.